# getting highcharts point id based on data from json

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts which renders barchart from data provided by json, which works fine. What I'm trying is, For each bar displayed on the chart, clicking on it must navigate to another page and the data that will be displayed on the navigated page should be based on the id of the clicked bar on the barchart. I am not sure how to go about doing this but this is what i have so far.

```
var values: Array<any> = [];
  var labels: Array<any> = [];
  var ids: Array<any> = [];
  this.service.getData(url).subscribe(
      data => {
          this.results = data;
          this.results.map(function(result){
              values.push(result.percentage);
              labels.push(result.displayName);
              ids.push(result.id);
          })
          this.chart = {
              title: {
                  text: '',
                  style: {
                      display: 'none'
                  }
              },
              credits: {
                  enabled: false
              },
              chart: {
                  type: 'bar',
                  marginLeft: 120
              },
              xAxis: {
                  categories: labels,
              },
              yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  title: {
                      text: '',
                      style: {
                          display: 'none'
                      }
                  },
                  labels: {
                      overflow: 'justify'
                  }
              },
              tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: ' %'
              },
              plotOptions: {
                  bar: {
                      dataLabels: {
                          enabled: false
                      }
                  },
                  series: {
                      pointWidth: 15,
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      point: {
                          events: {
                              click: function(){
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              },
              series: [{
                  showInLegend: false,
                  data: values,
                  name: 'demo'
              }]
          };

      }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

add highcharts PlotOption click event to your barchart which looks something like

```
plotOptions: {
       ... 
       ...
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    //event handling code
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

The idea is that, onclicking the bar, the window has to navigate to yourr second page which receives information using `GET` or `POST`

See this [Highcharts PlotOptions API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.events.click) and [Highcharts JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-click/) for more

Answer (score 0):

There is a module specially designated for this purpose and it is called `drilldown`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u4q55245/

Comment: Thanks i will look into this because i would like to be able to click on a bar which will navigate to another component which will display a new html page with new charts but all based on the bar info i clicked from. So i will need to be sure that i pass in the clicked bar data object so i can use to populate another html page.